# Social Studio - facebook multi brand

Tags: social-studio, social-contacts, social-customer-service

I'm asking this to understand if is the behaviour of social studio is "as it is intended" or we are  misunderstanding something.

We have different brands on facebook, each has its facebook page.

What we observe, is that if the same person contact us on different brand pages, we are not able to riconduct it to the same person, but Social studio creates "N" Social personas. Each one has a different "External ID". For external id, i mean the one indicated the the Salesforce documentation
(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_socialpersona.htm)

I'm not understanding if this is the expected behaviour or we have mis-configured something.

We would like to don't have duplicate Social personas in order to give more personalised customer service to our members/customers.

Maybe this is already described in the documentation, but i was not able to find it. If you have any clue, please help me.

Many thanks.